# Cordova app with targetSdkVersion 26 crashing on Android 8

Tags: cordova, meteor, android-8.0-oreo

I recently updated my Cordova (Meteor) app to target sdk version 26. Since the first day, the app started crashing on some of my users' devices with Android 8.0 and 8.1.

One user reported that the app often crashes when he receives a message in the app when it's in background mode. At this point we send a push notification (with `raix:push@3.0.2`), play a sound (with `brentjanderson:buzz@1.1.10`) and the screen changes as well (to show the message).

I understand this is likely due to the new [Background Service Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services). But it's hard to figure out what this means for a Cordova app as we don't control the source directly.

According to the crash logs from Android, ANRs has remained practically zero but crashes are happening every day. I've been unable to reproduce it with a test version of the app on a borrowed device.

For those who are familiar with the new limitations of SDK version 26, where is the issue likely to be?

Comment: When you use an old SDK it works as "compatibility mode" on OS with greater SDK version. As you increased the SDK version, you will probably need to updated most of the plugins as they might have been updated to support SDK 26.

Comment: I've realized the problem is purely due to push notifications, and most likely because of the `raix:push` message not being updated for [Android Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). The issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/raix/push/issues/341